# nginx access_by_lua: how to use twice

Tags: nginx, lua

```
access_by_lua '
    ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE, "Global access! Host: <" .. ngx.var.server_name .. ">");
';

log_by_lua '
    ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE, "End of request. Host: <" .. ngx.var.server_name .. ">");
';

server {
    listen       127.0.0.1:8890;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /tmp/local.access.log  upstreamlog;

    location /highload {

        access_by_lua '
            ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE, "Location access! Host: <" .. ngx.var.server_name .. ">");
        ';
        echo Hello;
    }
}
```

In this configuration file, I'd like to see log-outputs for "Global" and for "Location". But it is triggered only for "Location". Can anyone help or describe how it works?

Comment: As most of nginx directives, `access_by_lua` inherited from previous level only if it's not defined in current level. What the real problem is?

Comment: @AlexeyTen , I want monitor requests per second for every server inside nginx. Servers already have access_by_lua (for my needs). I just want increment counter in global access and decrement in global log.

Comment: access_by_lua is for access restrictions, not for logs. Probably you need log_by_lua